# Python If Statement Not Working when Testing Numbers Between 1 and 10

Tags: python, django

Trying to get the if statement to work.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
   return render(request, 'landscapes/index.html')

def landscape(request, id):
    print id
    if id>=1 and id<=10:
        print 'true'
        landscape = 'https://wildwithgrace.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/snowy-landscape.jpg'
    context = {
        'landscape': landscape
    }
    return render(request, 'landscapes/landscape.html', context)
```

Only will ever return UnboundLocalError at /# even when the number is Greater than 1 and Less than 10.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$', views.landscape),
]
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Check the type of id, may be you have to convert it into 'int' before if check.

Comment: @Exprator The code returns a unbound local error because I am only defining the variable landscapes within the if statement which is never true from a unknown reason even when id = 5

Comment: @AbdullahDanyal tried this if int(id)>=1 and id<=int(10): still no luck

Comment: what does print id returns in the console?

Comment: Then most probably the problem is that you are calling landscape from index, and in 'urls.py' file of this django project, you didnt define 'id' in its url.

Comment: @Exprator when the url is http://localhost:8000/5, the console will print id as 5

Comment: just post the urls.py, if you can

Comment: @AbdullahDanyal I used this in the urls.py: url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$', views.landscape),

Comment: @Exprator I added it above

Comment: does it print the true in the terminal if you give 5 as id?

Comment: @Exprator No, the only thing that prints is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def landscape(request, id):
    print id
    if int(id) >= 1 and int(id) <= 10:
        print 'true'
        landscape = 'https://wildwithgrace.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/snowy-landscape.jpg'
        context = {
            'landscape': landscape
        }
    else:
        context = {}
    return render(request, 'landscapes/landscape.html', context)
```

try this

Comment: And when you use this answer, **please** rename the context `landscape` variable to something different, say `requested_landscape`. Having the same name as the function will cause problems at some point.